# unable to install matplotlib 1.3 - import fails due to dateutil

Tags: matplotlib, ubuntu-12.04, python-dateutil

On Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop I uninstalled matplotlib 1.1.1 and tried installing matplotlib 1.3 via pip install matplotlib.

Everything seems to have worked but now when I try to import matplotlib I get the following:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 06:20:15) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/radek/remedy_reports/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 110, in <module>
    raise ImportError("matplotlib requires dateutil")
ImportError: matplotlib requires dateutil
```

The problem is that when I do pip freeze I get:

```
Cython==0.19.1
Jinja2==2.7
MarkupSafe==0.18
Pygments==1.6
Sphinx==1.1.3
argparse==1.2.1
docutils==0.11
ipython==1.0.0
matplotlib==1.3.0
nose==1.3.0
numpy==1.7.1
openpyxl==1.6.2
pandas==0.12.0-274-gc472099
pyodbc==3.0.7
pyparsing==2.0.1
python-dateutil==2.1
pytz==2013b
pyzmq==13.1.0
scikit-learn==0.13.1
scipy==0.12.0
six==1.4.1
tornado==3.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Dateutil is clearly there. If anyone share some light on why this is happening that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out uninstalling and installing python-dateutil using pip worked.

I can now import matplotlib just fine.